# How to create a multi-column matrix inside a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and struggling to replicate this matrix given by the sample data. This matrix contains two different sub-matrices inside.

```
> str(oliveoil)
'data.frame':   16 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ chemical: AsIs [1:16, 1:5] 0.73 0.19 0.26 0.67 0.52 0.26 0.24  0.3 0.35 0.19 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr  "G1" "G2" "G3" "G4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr  "Acidity" "Peroxide" "K232" "K270" ...
 $ sensory : AsIs [1:16, 1:6] 21.4 23.4 32.7 30.2 51.8 40.7 53.8 26.4 65.7   45 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr  "G1" "G2" "G3" "G4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr  "yellow" "green" "brown" "glossy" ...
```

However, when I create a data frame using the following command, I get a flat data frame with all matrices combined:

```
data.d <- data.frame( x1 = matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),nrow=3), x2 = matrix(c(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1),nrow=3), resp = matrix(c(20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20),nrow=3)  )
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Wrap them into `I` as in `data.d <- data.frame(x1 = I(matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),nrow=3)), x2 = I(matrix(c(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1),nrow=3)),  resp = I(matrix(c(20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20),nrow=3)))`. See `?data.frame`. And you haven't specified any dim names to your matrices.

Comment: The important bit is the `AsIs` part on the `str` output. A simple `?AsIs` will tell you how to do this (that is what @DavidArenburg told you already).

Comment: Great, thanks that worked :).